# How to re-commit a full branch to VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit

I'm hosting my code repository via Microsoft VSTS (free ^^). But I had some issues lately with my account, maybe because of my expired SSL certificate. Nonetheless, everything works again and I can also login to my account.

When I check the code I see no commits I've made in between are actually committed to my `feature/app-mvp` branch. The only branch there is at the moment.

Is there a way to re-commit all code to my hosted code repository again? When I do a `git status` I see:

```
On branch feature/app-mvp
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Should I make a back-up, do a `git checkout -b feature/app-mvp2` or something? Or is there another way to re-commit all the files in the current branch?

Comment: What do you mean "re-commit a full branch"? Do you want to change the latest commit on `feature/app-mvp` branch, or do you want to remove some commits on `feature/app-mvp`branch etc?

Comment: I mean I don't see the commits I made in the repository, so I would like to push all the files to the repository (like a first commit).

Comment: Ok, I added the way to push local commits to VSTS git repo. And you can have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push local commits to VSTS git repo,  you can use below steps:

1. Check if you have add VSTS git repo as the remote

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

   If it shows the remote (such as `origin`) with VSTS git repo URL, then push directly as step3 shows.
2. Add VSTS as a remote

   ```
   git remote add origin <VSTS git repo URL>
   ```

   **Note:** if the remote name `origin` is used for other remote repo, you can use a different remote name instead.
3. Push local commit to VSTS git repo

   ```
   git push -u origin feature/app-mvp
   ```

   **Note:** `-u` option means use `origin/feature/app-mvp` to tracking local `feature/app-mvp` branch. After that, it will show the relation between `feature/app-mvp` with `origin/feature/app-mvp` when you executing `git status`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it worked. I see a push entry now. Also there seemed to be a little caching issue maybe, since I now also see all the commits I made last week. +1A

Answer (score 1):

I have not used VSTS but if it is just a git repository, one way I can think is to delete the remote branch and push your local branch again.

WARNING: Please make sure you have everything on your local branch before deleting the remote branch. Also, you could theoretically lose your code if something goes wrong between deleting the remote branch and pushing your local branch to VSTS.

To delete:
`git push origin :feature/app-mvp`

To push your local branch:
`git push origin feature/app-mvp`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked just as you and Marina Liu - MSFT described. +1